# Categories mapping in magento

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to map the categories?
My wholesale uses another categories that i wanna use.

So on every import i need to change all the categories to my categories

Is there a way to automate this working flow?

Answer (score 0):

So far only way todo that it's extend default M2 import and rewrite part which import categories, here is some resources to help
- Example of extended M2 Import - https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree 
- Blog post with details about custom import implementation https://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-2-import-export-module-development/